# 'In salon' or 'at salon'

Tags: prepositions

I just found out I have no clue which preposition can I use with the word "salon". When i searched for it I found both. Can you please explain me the difference? The sentence I wanted to say was: "My mum gets on great *in/at* her salon."

Comment: [Maybe this can help (the difference between 'at' and 'in'.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87306/difference-between-at-and-in-when-specifying-location)

Comment: If you insert **with the staff**, your sentence is much improved. She gets on well with the staff at her salon. **In** is possible too but less likely.

Comment: It all depends what you're trying to say. If you mean your mother has good social interactions with others when she goes to this "salon", both ***in*** and ***at*** are fine (and mean *exactly* the same thing). BUT if your mother ***owns*** the salon, and you want to say that she's running the business successfully, that would be better / more idiomatically expressed by *My mum gets on great **with** her salon*.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always easy to decide which one to use when referring to location, but [YourDictionary](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/vs/using-at-vs-in-for-place-and-time-correctly.html) offers some useful guidelines:

> “At” is used when you are at the top, bottom or end of something; at a specific address; at a general location; and at a point.
> “In” is used in a space, small vehicle, water, neighborhood, city and country.

Now, ***to get on*** can mean *to have a good relationship with someone*, but i think in your sentence it means:

> to manage or deal with a situation, especially successfully:
>
> - How are you ***getting on*** in your new home? ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-on))

So it depends on which nuance you want to stress. This is only an interpretation by if you say:

> My mum gets on great ***in*** her salon.

you are considering whatever work happens ***in*** that enclosed space. This is the [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20in%20her%20salon%2Cwas%20at%20her%20salon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20in%20her%20salon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20at%20her%20salon%3B%2Cc0) use.

If you say

> My mum gets on great ***at*** her salon.

you treat the salon as a location, a point in space, rather as an enclosed space.

However, this is a negligible nuance, and people do not take much notice of it either when they use it themselves or when they hear it from someone else.

Comment: Thank you for the answer